# Haxe - Print command line arguments

Tags: haxe

Using the Haxe programming language, is it possible to print the command line arguments that are passed to an application?

I'm trying to re-write this Java program (which simply prints the command line arguments) in Haxe.

```
public class JavaExample{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like there might be a solution for php, neko, and cpp (using the Sys class, specifically Sys.args): http://haxe.org/api/sys

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since targets like JS(in browser) and Flash do not have concept of command line arguments. Haxe put such "system" target things in [Sys](http://haxe.org/api/sys) and the top level sys package.

```
class Example {
    public static function main():Void {
        for (arg in Sys.args())
            Sys.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to compile Haxe to Javascript (when Javascript is being used outside the browser, e.g., in a node.js server?)

Comment: Also, is the Sys class available for every target language (or just one or two of them)?

Comment: Sys is "available in neko, php, cpp" according to its doc (right below its class name).

Comment: Is the documentation likely to be up-to-date at this time, or is it possible that it contains outdated information (which may not reflect the current state of the Haxe programming language?)

Comment: The online doc is always in sync with the latest release version(at the moment it is Haxe 2.10).

Comment: I remember seeing this package: http://lib.haxe.org/p/nodejs which a few of these comments seem to be requesting. It adds the Sys object and sys package to JavaScript for Node.JS, but I haven't tried it just yet. You can install it with haxelib.

Comment: It's only me or `Sys.args()[0]` is **NOT** the own process name?!?

Comment: @VíctorR.Escobar No, `Sys.args()[0]` is not the own process name. `Sys.executablePath()` may or may not give what you want [depended on the target you use](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3401#issuecomment-169676191).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.... `Sys.argv[0]` in some script languages is equal to `Path.withoutDirectory(Sys.executablePath())` in haxe